# SOAP Fault recieved by JAX-WS Client is not throwing Exception

Tags: soap, jaxb, jax-ws, java-11

I refactored a JAX-WS client to run on Java11 (from Java8).  The refactored code now uses jax-ws\jaxb from jaxws-rt-2.3.2.jar instead of the java8 rt.jar.  The client is able to handle responses successfully when there isn't a fault but when a fault is received, it does NOT throw an Exception.

I have both old and new apps in 2 eclipse workspaces.  cxf-codegen-plugin 3.3.1 was used to generate the client artifacts in both.  In debug mode, I am able to see that the same request is handled differently in both.  While unmarshalling the response, the Java11 workspace creates the SOAP11Fault object w/o setting any of the object attributes (faultcode, faultstring, detail).  This is causing the SOAPFaultBuilder.createException() method to attempt to return a ProtcolException (which it does not find).  The Java8 workspace creates the SOAP11Fault with the necessary attributes and causes the SOAPFaultBuilder.createException() method to handle the exception correctly.  It appears that jaxb is not unmarshalling the XML message correctly in the jaxws-rt distribution.

W:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="urn:Service.ACME.v10.SomeProduct" xmlns:dt="urn:Data.ACME.v10.SomeProduct" xmlns:ft="urn:Fault.ACME.v10.SomeProduct" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="SomeProduct" targetNamespace="urn:Service.ACME.v10.SomeProduct">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:Data.ACME.v10.SomeProduct" xmlns:dt="urn:Data.ACME.v10.SomeProduct" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            ...
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:portType name="SomeProduct">
        <wsdl:operation name="CallExpressInquiry">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:ExpInq_InMsg"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:ExpInq_OutMsg"/>
            <wsdl:fault message="tns:InvalidInputErr_FaultMsg" name="InvalidInputErrFault"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="SomeProductSOAP" type="tns:SomeProduct">
        <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#SomeProductPolicy"/>
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="CallExpressInquiry">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.acme.org/SomeProduct/CallExpressInquiry"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
                <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#SomeProductPartsPolicy"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
                <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#SomeProductPartsPolicy"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="InvalidInputErrFault">
                <soap:fault use="literal" name="InvalidInputErrFault"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SomeProductService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:SomeProductSOAP" name="SomeProductSOAP">
            <soap:address location="https://uat.services.SomeProduct.com:8444/SomeProduct"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Response Payload:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The Following Sender Id Not Registered: 12345</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns2:InvalidInputError  xmlns:ns2="urn:Fault.ACME.v10.SomeProduct" xmlns="urn:Data.ACME.v10.SomeProduct">
                    <ns2:responseCode>307</ns2:responseCode>
                </ns2:InvalidInputError>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Code from jaxws-rt package (StubHandler class):

```
        public JavaCallInfo readResponse(Packet p, JavaCallInfo call) throws Throwable {
                Message msg = p.getMessage();
        if(msg.isFault()) {
->>>        SOAPFaultBuilder faultBuilder = SOAPFaultBuilder.create(msg);
->>>        Throwable t = faultBuilder.createException(checkedExceptions);
            call.setException(t);
            throw t;
        } else {
                initArgs(call.getParameters());
            Object ret = responseBuilder.readResponse(msg, call.getParameters());
            call.setReturnValue(ret);
            return call;
        }
        }
```

Old Workspace w/Java8 logs (working):

```
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:26 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber dumpFiberContext
FINE: engine-JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e: Stub for https://uat.services.ensurebill.com:8444/EnsureBillfiber-1 After tube execution with NO ACTION or MSG ID and 'current' tube com.sun.xml.internal.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube@571f07be.processResponse() from thread SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1 with Packet: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Packet@6ac6209f
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:26 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber dumpFiberContext
FINE: engine-JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e: Stub for https://uat.services.ensurebill.com:8444/EnsureBillfiber-1 After tube execution with NO ACTION or MSG ID and 'current' tube null.processResponse() from thread SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1 with Packet: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Packet@6ac6209f
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:26 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber _doRun
FINE: Thread leaving _doRun(): Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:26 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber completionCheck
FINE: engine-JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e: Stub for https://uat.services.ensurebill.com:8444/EnsureBillfiber-1 completed
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:28 PM java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager dispatchEvent
FINE: sun.awt.TimedWindowEvent[WINDOW_LOST_FOCUS,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on frame0
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:28 PM java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager dispatchEvent
FINE: Active javax.swing.JFrame[frame0,0,0,1216x732,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=Ensurebill SDK Sandbox v14.1.00.3 | Java Version: 1.8,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=EXIT_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,8,31,1200x693,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true], Current focused javax.swing.JFrame[frame0,0,0,1216x732,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=Ensurebill SDK Sandbox v14.1.00.3 | Java Version: 1.8,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=EXIT_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,8,31,1200x693,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true], losing focus javax.swing.JFrame[frame0,0,0,1216x732,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=Ensurebill SDK Sandbox v14.1.00.3 | Java Version: 1.8,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=EXIT_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,8,31,1200x693,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true] opposite null
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:28 PM java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager dispatchEvent
FINE: java.awt.FocusEvent[FOCUS_LOST,temporary,opposite=null,cause=ACTIVATION] on javax.swing.JTextArea[,0,0,440x640,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicBorders$MarginBorder@2a127b2a,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],colums=40,columWidth=11,rows=40,rowHeight=16,word=true,wrap=true]
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:28 PM java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager dispatchEvent
FINE: java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_DEACTIVATED,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on frame0
Keep-Alive-Timer, called close()
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeInternal(true)
Keep-Alive-Timer, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Keep-Alive-Timer, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 80
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeSocket(true)
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:39 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Trying to locate com/sun/xml/internal/ws/fault/jaxb.properties
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:39 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:39 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Trying to locate com/sun/xml/internal/ws/fault/jaxb.properties
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:39 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:39 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.bind.context.factory
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder lookupJaxbContextUsingOsgiServiceLoader
FINE: Unable to find from OSGi: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Checking META-INF/services
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Unable to find: META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Trying to create the platform default provider
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder safeLoadClass
FINE: Trying to load com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder newInstance
FINE: loaded com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory from jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/rt.jar!/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/ContextFactory.class
Sep 17, 2019 3:34:40 PM com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory createContext
FINE: Property com.sun.xml.internal.bind.XmlAccessorFactoryis not active.  Using JAXB's implementation
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:19 PM com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory createTransformerFactory
FINE: TransformerFactory instance: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl@5fd6be83
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Trying to locate com/sun/xml/internal/ws/fault/jaxb.properties
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.bind.context.factory
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder lookupJaxbContextUsingOsgiServiceLoader
FINE: Unable to find from OSGi: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Checking META-INF/services
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Unable to find: META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Trying to create the platform default provider
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:50 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder safeLoadClass
FINE: Trying to load com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:51 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder newInstance
FINE: loaded com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory from jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/lib/rt.jar!/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/ContextFactory.class
Sep 17, 2019 3:35:51 PM com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory createContext
FINE: Property com.sun.xml.internal.bind.XmlAccessorFactoryis not active.  Using JAXB's implementation
ensurebill.v10.tsysa.service.InvalidInputErrFaultMsg: The Following Sender Id Not Registered:F1273E49D2CA45C6AFD1413C1F0EF800
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:238)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
```

New Workspace w/Java11 logs (not throwing exception):

```
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber dumpFiberContext
FINE: engine-JAX-WS RI 2.3.2 git-revision#3d0bba4: Stub for https://uat.services.ensurebill.com:8444/EnsureBillfiber-1 After tube execution with NO ACTION or MSG ID and 'current' tube com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientLogicalHandlerTube@3d400f20.processResponse() from thread SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1 with Packet: com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.Packet@211f3a60
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber dumpFiberContext
FINE: engine-JAX-WS RI 2.3.2 git-revision#3d0bba4: Stub for https://uat.services.ensurebill.com:8444/EnsureBillfiber-1 After tube execution with NO ACTION or MSG ID and 'current' tube null.processResponse() from thread SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1 with Packet: com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.Packet@211f3a60
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber _doRun
FINE: Thread leaving _doRun(): Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber completionCheck
FINE: engine-JAX-WS RI 2.3.2 git-revision#3d0bba4: Stub for https://uat.services.ensurebill.com:8444/EnsureBillfiber-1 completed
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder find
FINE: Searching jaxb.properties
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder getSystemProperty
FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder getSystemProperty
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder getSystemProperty
FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.bind.context.factory
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder getSystemProperty
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder getSystemProperty
FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder getSystemProperty
FINE:   not found
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder firstByServiceLoaderDeprecated
FINE: Searching META-INF/services
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder firstByServiceLoaderDeprecated
FINE: Configured factorty class:com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder newInstance
FINE: loaded com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory from jar:file:/C:/Users/layanij/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/ContextFactory.class
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory createContext
FINE: Property com.sun.xml.bind.XmlAccessorFactoryis not active.  Using JAXB's implementation
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder getSystemProperty
FINE: Checking system property javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory
Sep 17, 2019 3:51:30 PM javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder logFound
FINE:   found com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl
```

Expecting the exception to be thrown in Java11 version workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, bad news.  The good news is that I was able to get it working.  The bad news is that I don't have any idea what did it.  After many hours trying to resolve it, I decided to create a new workspace from scratch and re-apply my changes manually. I ran it and the fault response finally threw an exception in my client "faultCode argument for createFault was passed NULL" which confirmed my prior observation. I was able to find info online that suggested that the response might not be inline with the schema.  I validated the XML payload against the schema and it was valid.  I rebuilt the project with maven from the command prompt (outside of eclipse) and restarted the retested the application.  The attributes of the fault where now populated correctly and my client is able to handle faults as expected.  My only advise here for those developing in eclipse is that if all else fails, build a new workspace and see if that helps.